# Average MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, average

The only thing I am trying to do is to get the average of Emision_C02 consumed at 10pm for all the days in location:1. The collection, db.datos_sensores2, has documents within like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609c2c2d420a73728827e87f"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-07-01T02:15:00Z"),
    "sensor_id" : 1,
    "location_id" : 1,
    "medidas" : [
        {
            "tipo_medida" : "Temperatura",
            "valor" : 14.03,
            "unidad" : "ºC"
        },
        {
            "tipo_medida" : "Humedad_relativa",
            "valor" : 84.32,
            "unidad" : "%"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609c2c2d420a73728827e880"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-07-01T02:15:00Z"),
    "sensor_id" : 2,
    "location_id" : 1,
    "medidas" : [
        {
            "tipo_medida" : "Emision_CO2",
            "valor" : 1.67,
            "unidad" : "gCO2/m2"
        },
        {
            "tipo_medida" : "Consumo_electrico",
            "valor" : 0.00155,
            "unidad" : "kWh/m2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrote this:

```
db.datos_sensores2.aggregate([
{$project:{timestamp:{$dateFromString:{dateString:'$timestamp'}},"_id":0, "me-didas":{$slice:["$medidas",-1]},"location_id":1}},
{$addFields:{Hora:{$hour:"$timestamp"}}},
{$match:{'Hora':{$in:[10]},'medidas.tipo_medida':"Emision_CO2", "location_id":1}},
{$group:{ _id: null, Avg_Emision_CO2:{$avg: "$medidas.valores"}}}])
```

But nothing happen....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/-LqswomHWsY

I have noticed few things first of all hour comes to be 2 in above example and not 10. Second the variable/field names are not correct so i have updated it.

```
[{$unwind: {
  path: '$medidas',
}}, {$addFields: {
  Hora: {
    $hour: "$timestamp"
  }
} }, {$match: {
  "Hora": {
    $in: [2] 
  },
  "medidas.tipo_medida": "Emision_CO2",
  "location_id": 1
}  }, {$group: {
  _id: null,
  Avg_Emision_CO2: {
    $avg: "$medidas.valor"
  }
}}]
```

Pipeline stages:

- unwind: as $medidas is array we can unwind it so it will be easy to filter only "Emision_CO2",
- addfield: add houre from timestamp
- match: to match "medidas.tipo_medida": "Emision_CO2",
- group: to get average
  [image]

Comment: Hi Programmer Analyst, thank you so much for your time! I only had to make some changes but your help was incredibly helpful! thank you for your time and speciallly for your explenation. It helped me to understand: `db.datos_sensores2.aggregate([{$project:{timestamp:{$dateFromString:{dateString:'$timestamp'}},"_id":0, "medidas":{$slice:["$medidas",1]},"location_id":1, "sensor_id":1}},{$unwind:{path:"$medidas",}},{$addFields:{Hora:{$hour:'$timestamp'}}},{$match:{"Hora":{$in:[10]},"medidas.tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2","location_id":1}},{$group:{_id:null,Avg_Emision_CO2:{$avg:"$medidas.valor"}}}])`